# How do I do a reverse ssh proxy without being able to ssh to my proxy host?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have two hosts sitting side by side:
Host 1 = Linux OS on local network 192.168.0.x
--I have full admin rights. I can ssh out and into this host.
Host 2 = Mac OS X. Two interfaces:
--No admin rights. I can ssh out from this host but not into it.
--Int 1 is on local network 192.168.0.x
--Int 2 is on restricted network 10.123.123.x 
I need to be able to access web pages on 10.123.123.x from Host 1. I used to do it with SSH tunneling to Host 2 but I can no longer ssh to Host 2 due to policy change.
How do I create a reverse tunnel or proxy from Host 2 to Host 1 without having to log into Host 2?
Edit: To clarify: I have physical access to Host 2. I can ssh out of Host 2 but not into host 2. That's why I categorized this as a reverse proxy.

Comment: You can't. It's not possible to connect *via* a host without somehow connecting *to* that host in the first place.

Comment: Since you have _no access whatsoever_ to Host2, the only way to _access it_ and create a tunnel to Host1 is via remote exploits or social engineering. Start with befriending the policy makers ;-)

Comment: To clarify: I have access to Host 2. I can ssh out from Host 2. I cannot ssh into Host 2.